# NULL value in Avro column is loaded as VARIANT NULL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm bulk loading data to Snowflake using stage with avro files. Column in snowflake table is of type VARIANT is defined as union of null&string in avro file. Sadly null value in avro for such column is loaded into Snowflake as `VARIANT null` instead of regular `SQL NULL`. It complicates my subsequent MERGE query. Here is my COPY query:

```sql
copy into PUBLIC."_bp_staging_1621364335535_xxx"
    from @~/batches
    file_format = (type = avro compression = auto)
    MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE
    pattern = '.*parallel_batch_18441164121617616245\.avro$';
```

I can of course use `NULL_IF` parameter but then I'd have to emit that value for every empty VARIANT field which seems pretty wasteful to me.

Is there better way ?

Answer (score 0):

> *"Sadly null value in avro for such column is loaded into Snowflake as VARIANT null instead of regular SQL NULL. It complicates my subsequent MERGE query"*

> [NULL Values](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#null-values)
>
> **To convert a VARIANT “null” value to SQL NULL, cast it as a string.**

Comment: Thank you, Lukasz. Yes, I can cast it, but I'd rather not because that would require me to enumerate all columns in COPY query.

Comment: I was rather thinking about the usage in MERGE or computed column. I see you already found `IS_NULL_VALUE` which could be alternative to `variant_col:sth::string IS NULL`

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try that too, to see which uses less compute.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to change this behavior but engineer from Snowflake suggested altering my MERGE query instead.

In MERGE query I use `column is not null` when condition in one of the cases of update section. Instead, he suggested to use `IS_NULL_VALUE` function which I do only for VARIANT destination columns.